# Using Xpath navigator to get the average price of two products in xml document

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<products>
    <product id="1">
        <name>Cigarettes</name>
        <price>5</price>
        <stack>On stack</stack>
        <date>19.11.2016</date>
    </product>

    <product id="2">
        <name>Frozen vegetables</name>
        <price>10</price>
        <stack>Not on stack</stack>
        <date>22.08.2014</date>
    </product>
</products>
```

And I am trying to calculate and write the average price of these two products like this:

```
static void calculateAverage()
    {
        XPathDocument docNav = new XPathDocument("Products.xml");
        XPathNavigator nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
        string xpath = "sum(/products/product/price) div count(/products/product/price)";
        XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select(xpath);

        Console.WriteLine("\nAverage price is {0}eur", nav.Evaluate(xpath));
    }
```

It throws an exception "Expression must evaluate to a node-set." at the "XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select(xpath)" line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Evaluate` instead of `Select` for XPath expressions that might return a string, boolean or number rather than a node set - your `Console.WriteLine` line is correct, the `Select` call is un-necessary.

Comment: I did as you said. It writes in console now, but the value is NaN instead of number. Do i have to do any conversions of some kind or...?

Comment: Oh nevermind. i had a mistake in .xml file. Works great now. Thanks!